# awk command to replace string using regex

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file with content as below, there are no new lines:

```
1234%#@@!#12346@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++456789%#@@!#12346@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#
```

i want the file to be modified as

```
1234%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++456789%#@@!@!#@!#@!#@!#
```

i.e. anything coming between delimiter `@!#` and the next delimiter `@!#` should be made null.

Any pointers to this will be useful. Thanks a lot

Comment: So, why isn't the output `1234%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#` ? What special about `+++++456789%#@`? That string is between those delimiters.

Comment: You're saying *anything* between delimiter `@!#` and the next delimiter `@!#` should be made null, which I think would mean your result would be, `1234%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!##@@!@!#@!#@!#@!#` so do you have some other requirement? Only true if what's in between are digits only perhaps?

Comment: The file has no newlines. Anything between the delimiters @!# should be made NULL. %#@ and +++++ are other delimiters. Value between them should remain as is.

Comment: File Content - 1234%#@@!#12346@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++456789%#@@!#12346@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++++201546987@!#123456@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++++                                                                                      This to be modified as1234%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++456789%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++++201546987@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++++

Comment: Don't try to put formatted content in comments. Edit your question to show precise, formatted, testable input and output.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some verbose perl:

```perl
use strict;

# read the file, the filename is given as a parameter to the perl script
open my $f, "<", shift; 
my $data = <$f>; 
close $f;

# the possible delimeters
my @delims = qw( @!# %#@ +++++ );

# split the data into an array of intermixed fields and delimiters
my $delim_re = join "|", map {quotemeta} @delims;
my @fields_and_delims = split /($delim_re)/, $data;;

for (my $i=2; $i < @fields_and_delims; $i+=2) {
    # empty this element if between "@!#" delimiters
    $fields_and_delims[$i] = "" if $fields_and_delims[$i-1] eq $delims[0] 
                               and $fields_and_delims[$i+1] eq $delims[0];
}

# the output, with no trailing newline
print join "", @fields_and_delims;
```

Then

```
$ printf "%s" "1234%#@@!#12346@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++456789%#@@!#12346@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++‌​++201546987@!#123456@!#4562366@!#@!#@!#+++++++" > file
$ perl script.pl file
1234%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++456789%#@@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++‌​++201546987@!#@!#@!#@!#@!#+++++++
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn!! Pardon my ignorance as I am new to unix, can we achieve this in  unix

Comment: perl is just a command like awk or sed is a command. Assuming perl is installed (surprising if not), this can be run on any "unix" computer.